# Avoid disable unused applications in windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-10

I have created an application that is running in the background and on windows 10 I have seen that after some time this app will be disabled. How can I avoid this and my app is always on?

### EDIT 1:

It's a winforms app that we minimize in the system tray. We don't recive any message why it's disabled. Where can i found eventually messages or log for the reason?

### EDIT 2:

It's a win form, which use a serial port to communicate with an external device. The thing is that the program needs to wait for special messages of the device, which are send every few weeks. There is also implemented a logic which prevents that the pc is going in standby, by this way the pc is running 24/7. The program works perfectly on several pc with win7. When the program is running on win10 it is also working fine for the first few days, but at a certain point the program gets shutdown by the system (win10 only!) and I don’t get why.

Comment: running in background but tag as winforms?  And could you provide more details of _some time this app will be disabled_, and disabled by any reason?

Comment: Can you clarify what is **disabled**? It closed or other?

Comment: @alex see the post below of anton that explanes the case a little bit more

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those information, we don't suggest any _non-answer_ to post as answer, especially clarify the question

Comment: Have you check the event log, to see whether the pc closed (e.g. windows update with force restart). Moreover, try to output heartbeat to event log, so you can track when your application closed, and what event occur at that moment.